# cannot coerce type in R when exporting the data.frame

Tags: r, excel, character

I want to export the data.frame into excel and my code is as follows.

`wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook()`

```
sheet_growth  <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName="growth")
```

And  then the Rstudio reports that

> Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
>     cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

I have tried really hard to figure out what happened. But still cannot work it out. Any thoughts would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Is this openxlsx? You really need to specify; there are a lot of Excel i/o packages.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which library you are using is difficult to help you.
This is what I usually use

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(df, fulloutfn, showNA = FALSE)
```

where `df` is the data frame you want to save, `fulloutfn` is the fully qualified filename (with path).

Hope it help you.

Regards, Umberto

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your reminder . I add

`xlsx::`

before all the function and it finally works out. It turns out that I also library the packages openxlsx, which means that the default function of `createsheet` would be of packages openxlsx.

Answer (score 0):

`write.csv(nameOfData file="theNameYouWant")`

This would be the easiest.